# Python script is not working on the browser. - Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I've successfully installed Python 3.3.2 in Ubuntu Linux server.

Here is the hello.py codes.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

As you noticed, I use Flask for framework.
After I wrote down this codes, I started to run the python.

```
#python hello.py
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```

I saw that it was running.

and I typed the domain address on chrome browser that is connect to Ubuntu server.

http://example.com:5000/

However, it was loading for 10 seconds, and it failed to connect the server on the browser.

I checked all the logs in /var/log, but couldn't find the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a firewall on your server. It's blocking port 5000.

If you want to check if it's running or not you can use wget on your servers shell:

```
wget http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

It will connect and download the page to current directory. You could check the content of the file and you will see `Hello World` if it's working.

Comment: You can change your firewall (probably iptables) configuration, or you could even stop it. If you are using this server on production, I do not recommend that. If you close your firewall (`service iptables stop`) you could open the page.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem you would accept that and perhaps give an upvote :), If you don't do so your questions will seem to be unanswered. That's the rules :)

Comment: Yes, I had to wait for 5 mins to accept your answer. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You should run it on [localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost):

```
app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

or just

```
app.run()
```

Comment: check your Firewall settings

Comment: Thanks I checked Firewall.